# shadow in Android react-native

Tags: android, react-native, shadow

[How can I achieve a shadow in Android that drops at the top of a View component? Like the image attached where the card has a top shadow. Elevation has a fixed light point which always create a bottom drop shadow unlike iOS options where I can change the offset. I've looked into packages such as react-native-shadows but it seems to have a big impact on performance and isn't as crisp as native shadows. Is there any other alternatives?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJVkP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Generator for shadow: https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/

Comment: It work fine on iOS but in android the shadow shown Just in the bottom of my View

Comment: hmm.. works fine here. may try some more height, margin or padding? it couldt be overflow hidden